# Html input type "email" and input type "number" different style other than input type "text"

Tags: html, css, validation, styles, stylesheet

I request a help to fix a style issue in the below form . (im not a programmer, just trying stuff)

This is the code

```
<form action="success.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your name..." required /><br />
<input type="number" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required title="Valid phone number (Without + marks)"/><br />
<input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required title="Valid Email Format:example@example.com" /><br />
<textarea name="Message" placeholder="Your Message" required /></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send my Quote Request" id="submit_footer" /><br />
</form>
```

and this is output..

[image]

which has a different formatting for **input type="number"** and **input type="email"**. (

```
<input type="number" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required title="Valid phone number (Without + marks)"/><br />
<input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required title="Valid Email Format:example@example.com" /><br />
```

)

**Input type="text"** is the ok format/style. (`<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your name..." required /><br />`)

I wish to have same formatting which is used for   for both in put type "email" and "number".

Could not figure out even with google. Any help would be appreciated.

KR

**PS**

**Style sheet footer**

```
/*--------------------------------------------------footer--------------------------------*/
.footer
{

    background:#00234d;
    padding:50px 0px;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.footer h3
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.footer input[type='text']
{
    width:251px;
    height:33px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    outline:0px;
    color:#919191;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:transparent;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.footer textarea
{
    width:251px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:15px;
    background:transparent;
    height:85px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    outline:0px;
    color:#919191;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    font-size:14px;

}
#submit_footer {
  color: #00aceb;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline:0;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:transparent;
  width:270px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 3px solid #00aceb;
  transition: all .5s !important;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s !important;
  -o-transition: all .5s !important;
  -ms-transition: all .5s !important;
  -moz-transition: all .5s !important;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, #009ad6 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
}
#submit_footer:hover
{
     background-position:left bottom;
     color:#FFF;
}
.w_float
{
    float:left;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
      margin-top: 90px;
}
.w_float p
{
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    color:#c3c7c8;
}
.w_float ul
{
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
}
.w_float ul li
{
    list-style:none;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    background:url(../images/true_arrow.png) no-repeat left 5px;
    color:#c3c7c8;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:0px 30px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.s li
{
    background:url(../images/privacy_safe.png) no-repeat left 5px !important;
      padding: 0px 40px !important;
      transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.w_float2 ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.w_float2 ul li
{
    list-style:none;

    background-image:url(../images/footer_ul.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:0px 30px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    font-weight:600;
}
.w_float2 ul li:nth-child(2)
{
    background-position:0px -51px;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
.w_float2 ul li a
{

    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:18px;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

Comment: Provide your css code

Comment: You have already provided html code . Need your css code to solve this issue

Comment: @Anuresh  stylesheet for footer added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have applied css only on `.footer input[type='text']`...you will need to provide the same css to `input[type='number']` and `input[type='email']` like

```
.footer input[type='text'],
.footer input[type='email'],
.footer input[type='number'] {
  width: 251px;
  height: 33px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #919191;
  outline: 0px;
  color: #919191;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all .5s !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s !important;
  -o-transition: all .5s !important;
  -ms-transition: all .5s !important;
  -moz-transition: all .5s !important;
}
```

...or another solution will be, which I recommend, use same class in all the input types, lets say `input-control` like

HTML

```
<input class="input-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name" required/><br />
<input class="input-control" type="number" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required title="Valid phone number (Without + marks)"/><br />
<input class="input-control" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required title="Valid Email Format:example@example.com" /><br />
```

CSS

```
.footer .input-control {
  width: 251px;
  height: 33px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #919191;
  outline: 0px;
  color: #919191;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all .5s !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s !important;
  -o-transition: all .5s !important;
  -ms-transition: all .5s !important;
  -moz-transition: all .5s !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.footer input[type='email']
{
    width:251px;
    height:33px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    outline:0px;
    color:#919191;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:transparent;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}

    .footer input[type='number']
{
    width:251px;
    height:33px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    outline:0px;
    color:#919191;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:transparent;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.footer input[type='text'] ,
.footer input[type="email"] ,
.footer input[type="number"]
{
    width:251px;
    height:33px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border:2px solid #919191;
    outline:0px;
    color:#919191;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:transparent;
    transition:all .5s !important; -webkit-transition:all .5s !important;-o-transition:all .5s !important;-ms-transition:all .5s !important;-moz-transition:all .5s !important;
}
```

Replace this in css